# Unable to edit PATH in User Environment Variable in Windows 10

Tags: c, gcc, mingw-w64

Recently I downloaded the gcc complier for C. After downloading, I copied the path of bin present inside mingw64 folder and tried to paste that inside PATH of user variable of advanced system settings, but, there, I m unable to add the path of bin in PATH.

Whenever, I am clicking on edit Path, then, I am getting this:

[image: screenshot of edit user variable dialog]

which is making it impossible to edit it.

[image: Picture of my Environment Variable]:

Comment: Why does that make it impossible to edit? Just press the left arrow key, and then paste. Don't forget that you need to add a `;` between the path you are adding and the existing paths.

Comment: Your first screenshot (or second; I think they are swapped; sorry if it was me) seems to show that you can edit, see johns comment. In the second you have a button "Edit..." which is very promising. Please describe what happens if you click it.

Comment: This is borderline off-topic. But I chose to accept it as covered by the exception for "tools programmers regularily need to use".

Comment: @john Thanks sir for helping me out. It has worked successfully

Answer (score 1):

Your first screenshot (or second; I think they are swapped; sorry if it was me) seems to show that you can edit, see comment by john.

> Just press the left arrow key, and then paste. Don't forget that you need to add a `;` between the path you are adding and the existing paths.

In the second you have a button "Edit...", which I clicked to get more editing options, adding a new one, editing (another "Edit..." button), reordering. Very convenient.

Comment: @john I quoted you. Let me know if/when you made your own answer. I will happily delete that part and let you have the reward for it.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. It has worked successfully.